# matching elements in multi columns from two files, then update or union them

Tags: excel, awk, sed

file1:

```
77, 4, -3, A0080
235, 5, -1, K0511
```

file2:

```
A0132, 77, -1, -2,  19.776
00000, 77, 4, -3,  18.608,
A0794, 235, -2, -2,  22.81
A0796, 235, -2, -5,  12.27
00000, 235, 5, -1,  18.992
```

desired output:

```
A0132, 77, -1, -2,  19.776
A0080, 77, 4, -3,  18.608,
A0794, 235, -2, -2,  22.81
A0796, 235, -2, -5,  12.27
K0511, 235, 5, -1,  18.992
```

basically to match column1, column2, column3 of file1 into column2, column3, column4 of file2, if match then replace the column1 of file2 by the value of column4 of file1.

I used:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2,$3]++;next} a[$2,$3,$4]  {print $0}' file1 file2
```

to get the output

```
00000, 77, 4, -3,  18.608,
00000, 235, 5, -1,  18.992
```

Then I am stuck.  Please help.  BTW, this is for 2 files, how's about more than 2 files in general.

Comment: Try to provide some feedback: did the answer work to you?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some problem with trailing spaces. This complicates things a little bit, because you need to do the trick `$field+=0` to overcome it (it removes trailing spaces).

You can try with this:

```
awk -F"," -v OFS=","
    'FNR==NR {$1+=0; $2+=0; $3+=0; a[$1,$2,$3]=$4;next}
     {$2+=0; $3+=0; $4+=0
      if (($2,$3,$4) in a) {$1=a[$2,$3,$4]}
      print
     }' f1 f2
```

Basically, it stores the value in the 4th column with index (1st, 2nd, 3rd) columns. Then, when reading the second file, it checks if the given index matches the 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns there; if so, it replaces the 1st field.

For your given input, it returns:

```
$ awk -F"," -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR {$1+=0; $2+=0; $3+=0; a[$1,$2,$3]=$4;next} {$2+=0; $3+=0; $4+=0; if (($2,$3,$4) in a) {$1=a[$2,$3,$4]} print}' f1 f2
A0132,77,-1,-2,  19.776
A0080,77,4,-3,  18.608,
A0794,235,-2,-2,  22.81
A0796,235,-2,-5,  12.27
K0511,235,5,-1,  18.992
```

Comment: replace the 1st field of file2 $1=a[$2,$3,$4]  why not a[$1,$2,$3] as this is 4th field of file1 ?

Comment: Please ignore this. I got it as the key(s)/index is from file2 but value of a is 4th column of file1).

Comment: it works. Thanks. Also, thank for trailing spaces info; how to remove the leading spaces

Comment: Is anyway to check to see if any duplicate items in the 1st column of the output file using awk ?  (Right now, I am using unix command to check the output file separately, but if it can be check while doing this, it is better.  Thanks.

Comment: @maria not very sure what you mean. Can you update your original question with some sample input and desired output? Note that if it is a new, different requirement, you would probably get more attention by posting a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file1 file2 \
 | sed -n 'H;${x
:cycle
# \n
#:11
# 77, 4, -3, A0080
#^2222222222 44444
#^33
# A0132, 77, -1, -2,  19.776
#^55555555555555555555555555
# 00000, 77, 4, -3,  18.608,
#^       2222222222
   s/\(\n\)\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\) \([A-Z0-9]*\)\(.*\)00000, \2/\1\2 \4\5\4, \2/
   t cycle
:clean
   s/\(\n\)\([^,]*,\)\{3\} [A-Z0-9]*\1/\1/g
   t clean
   s/^\n//
   p
   }'
```

posix sed (so `--posix`on GNU sed). line statring with `#^` give the grouping index in the line above so `2222222222` is the content of `\2` used later in the pattern

- load all line in working buffer
- find occurence of each triplet [ `(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)` in `s///` line after `:cycle`] in later line [ the `\2` ] with `00000,` as prefix, replace by following 'name' of the triplet [ ``4`]
- if found/replace, retry (1 change embrass next triplet so a `g` will always make only 1 change max) via `t cycle` that mean *if s/// occur, goto the label cycle, if not continue to next line*
- clean the triplet (replace any line, pattern starting with new line, that have the fingerprint of a triple by just the new line [ `\1` in this case ] and remove first new line that was added by using a `h` on first line that append the current line to the buffer (so first line is just a new line)
- print the result

Comment: Well done, I usually avoid sed for multiple files but you made it work.

Comment: I think you can simplify it a bit like this: `cat file1 file2 | sed -n 'H;${x;:cycle;s/\(\n\)\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\) \([A-Z0-9]*\)\(.*\)00000, \2/\5\4, \2/;t cycle;p}'`

Comment: Thanks for the info . Would you explain in details more on bullet 2, 3, 4 ? I am just learning sed recently so I might not know mụch ? Thanks.

Comment: added some comment in post

Comment: @A.Danischewski you can only simplify IF there is only 1 occurence of the missing triplet, if not you loose the mulptiple occurence and the request don't specify this (but you could assume it, so OK)

Answer (score 0):

`awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{max++;a1[FNR]=$1;a2[FNR]=$2;a3[FNR]=$3;a4[FNR]=$4;next} {done=0;for (i=0;i<$max;i++) {if ($2==a1[i] && $3==a2[i] && $4=a3[i]) {$1=""; print a4[i]","$0; done=1; break}}; if (done==0){ print}}' file1 file2`

Or easier to read:

```
awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{ ## process file 1  
   max++;               ## keep track of how many entries in file 1 
   a1[FNR]=$1;          ## build separate arrays for each field we care about
   a2[FNR]=$2;
   a3[FNR]=$3;
   a4[FNR]=$4;
   next}                ## go to next file 
  {done=0;              ## set a flag so we know when we have no match 
   for (i=0;i<$max;i++) ## loop over all array entries in file 1  
   {if ($2==a1[i] && $3==a2[i] && $4=a3[i]) ## if columns match in our pairing   
     {$1="";            ## get rid of column 1   
      print a4[i]","$0; ## print out file 1 column 4 & column 2 onward for file 2 
      done=1;           ## set the flag so we know we had a match 
      break}};          ## break for loop, no need to waste time processing more
     if (done==0) {     ## if we did not match, print out the existing file 2 line 
        print}}'    
file1 file2
```

If you want to extend for more files you can add more clauses setting the ARGV of the filename like this (of course changing the logic to what you want) - also if you want it to be automated and flexible you can build this with a shell loop and use `eval` to execute it:

```
 awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[FNR]=$0;a1[FNR]=$1;a2[FNR]=$2;a3[FNR]=$3;a4[FNR]=$4;next}
      FILENAME==ARGV[2]{b[FNR]=$0;b2[FNR]=$2;b3[FNR]=$3;b4[FNR]=$4;next}
      FILENAME==ARGV[3]{print "hi" a1[FNR] b2[FNR]}' file1 file2 file3
```

Update to handle the data results listed in the comments:

`awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{max++;a[FNR]=$0;a1[FNR]=$1;a2[FNR]=$2;a3[FNR]=$3;a4[FNR]=$4;$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";a[FNR]=$0;gsub(",+$","",a[FNR]);next} {done=0;for (i=0;i<$max;i++) {if ($2==a1[i] && $3==a2[i] && $4=a3[i]) {$1=""; gsub(",+$","",$0);gsub(" +","",a[i]);print " "a4[i]$0","a[i]; done=1; break}}; if (done==0){ print}}' file1 file2`

Changes that are made are to add the end fields from file 1 and clean up some cosmetics:

```
awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]
## save $0 in new array
{max++;a[FNR]=$0;a1[FNR]=$1;a2[FNR]=$2;a3[FNR]=$3;a4[FNR]=$4; 
## skip the first fields of new array up to field 4 and rid the trailing comma  
$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";a[FNR]=$0;gsub(",+$","",a[FNR]); next} 
{done=0;for (i=0;i<$max;i++) {if ($2==a1[i] && $3==a2[i] && $4=a3[i]) 
{$1=""; gsub(",+$","",$0);gsub(" +","",a[i]); ## rid unnecessary whitespace 
## print the rest of file 1 line entry 
print " "a4[i]$0","a[i]; done=1; break}}; if (done==0){ print}}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it today to see the result.  One thing I forgot if file1 has more columns, how can I include it in the desired output if it is a match.  For example,                                           

file1:

77, 4, -3, A0080, tom, susan,
235, 5, -1, K0511, bill, ted,

file2:

A0132, 77, -1, -2,  19.776
00000, 77, 4, -3,  18.608,
A0794, 235, -2, -2,  22.81
A0796, 235, -2, -5,  12.27
00000, 235, 5, -1,  18.992

desired output:

A0132, 77, -1, -2,  19.776
A0080, 77, 4, -3,  18.608, tom, susan
A0794, 235, -2, -2,  22.81
A0796, 235, -2, -5,  12.27
K0511, 235, 5, -1,  18.992, bill, ted,

Comment: thank for trailing spaces info; how to remove the leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^(.*,)\s*(.*)|s/^(.*,) \1/\2, \1/|' file1 | sed -rf - file2
```

Create a sed script from file1 to run against file2.